# Bash: Remove headers from HTTP response

Tags: regex, perl, bash, sed, grep

If I have some text containing HTTP headers and body, eg:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=38
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Fri, 22 Nov 2013 06:15:01 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 22 Nov 2013 06:14:01 GMT
Vary: *
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Fri, 22 Nov 2013 06:14:22 GMT

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My website</title>
</head>
<body>

Hello world!

</body>
</html>
```

and this text is being piped in from a command, how can I remove the headers to leave just the body?

(Within the headers, `\r\n` is used as the line break.  `\r\n\r\n` marks the end of the headers and the start of the body.)

Here's what I've tried (`...` indicates any command such as `cat` or `curl` which will output some HTTP headers and body to stdout):

### sed

My first idea was to do substitution with `sed`, to remove everything before the first occurrence of `\r\n\r\n`:

```
... | sed 's|^.*?\r\n\r\n||'
```

But this doesn't work, mainly because `sed` only operates on individual lines, so it can't operate on `\r` or `\n`.  (In addition, it doesn't support the `?` non-greedy operator.)

### grep

I also thought of using `grep` with a positive lookbehind for `\r\n\r\n`:

```
... | grep -oP '(?<=\r\n\r\n).*'
```

But this doesn't work either (mainly because `grep` only operates on individual lines).

`pcregrep` has a multiline mode (`-M`), but `pcregrep` is often not available (it's not installed by default in Ubuntu 12.04, Mac OS X 10.7, etc), and I'd like a solution which doesn't require any non-standard tools.

### perl

I then thought of doing substitution with `perl`, using the `/s` modifier so that `.` matches line breaks:

```
... | perl -pe 's/^.*?\r\n\r\n//s'
```

I think this is closer to a working solution.  However, I think Perl's Input Record Separator (`$/`) is `\n` by default, and needs to be changed to `\r\n`, so that `.` can match `\r\n`.  The `-0` option can be used to set `$/` to a single character, but not multiple characters.  I've tried this, but I don't think it's correct:

```
... | perl -pe '$/ = "\r\n"; s/^.*?\r\n\r\n//s'
```

Also, I think `^` is matching "start of line", but needs to match "start of file".

### Offset and substring

I had an idea of getting the offset of `\r\n\r\n` using:

```
BodyOffset=$(expr index "$MyHttpText" "\r\n\r\n")
```

and then extracting the body as a substring using:

```
HttpBody=${MyHttpText:BodyOffset}
```

Unfortunately, the Mac OS X version of `expr` doesn't support `index`.  Also, if possible, I'd like a solution which doesn't require the creation of variables.

### Parameter substitution

One other idea I had was to use parameter substitution, where `#` means "Remove from `$MyHttpText` the shortest part of `*\r\n\r\n` that matches the front end of `$MyHttpText`":

```
HttpBody=${MyHttpText#*\r\n\r\n}
```

But I'm not sure how to use this in a piped sequence of commands, and again I'd prefer a solution which doesn't require variables.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[sed](/questions/tagged/sed) can do this:

```
sed '1,/^$/d' data.txt
```

This command deletes everything starting from line 1, and ending at the first occurrence of an empty line (`^$`). This works if you have `\n` as a newline character. If you have `\r\n` as a newline character, you can use `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` to convert them back and forth or you can add the `\r` character to the [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) regex:

```
sed '1,/^\r$/d' data.txt
```

However, the last line will only work if you have `\r\n` as a newline character, to make it work on both types of newlines, you can use:

```
sed '1,/^\r\{0,1\}$/d' data.txt
```

Here we are looking for an empty line with either 0 or 1 `\r` characters.

Comment: And does that also work when line endings are `\r\n`?

Comment: It needs some tweaking, but it works. See my answer.

Comment: Lovely solution, many thanks! I haven't used `sed`'s delete function `d` before, but I can see this is a perfect situation to use it. Mac OS X uses the BSD version of `sed`, which doesn't understand the `\r` escape sequence, but this can be fixed by using `$'\r'`. So `sed '1,/^'$'\r''$/d'` works on Mac and Ubuntu.

Comment: If you use `fish` the syntax would be: `sed '1,/^'\r'$/d'`

Comment: In order to work with both `\r\n` and `\n` you could use the command `tr -d '\r' < data.txt | sed '1,/^$/d'`

Answer (score 2):

Your Perl one-line command does not (can not) remove the headers, because it reads only one line of input at the time. You need to unset the input record separator to read the whole input as one line.

```
perl -0777 ...
```

Comment: This works! Many thanks for clarifying the correct use of the input record separator in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Also fun to do in bash (internal commands only):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read LINE                     #<-- while you can read line from input
do                                  #<-- do the following actions
    if    [ $FLAG ]                 #<-- if:   this flag is set
    then  echo "$LINE"              #<--       echo the input to output
    elif  [ ${LINE:0:1} = $'\r'  ]  #<-- else: if line starts with \r
    then  FLAG=true                 #<--       then raise the flag
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
... | perl -ne 'print if $after_header; $after_header = 1 if /^\r$/'
```

Answer (score 0):

curl doesn't return headers by default from bash, unless you specify the -I option (capital i) or -D (dump headers). So make cure none of those are specified in your curl call!