# Remove HTTP Headers from CURL

Tags: html, bash, curl, sed

I have the same problem described in

[Bash: Remove headers from HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179623/bash-remove-headers-from-http-response)

The problem is that my output consists of more than one single blank line so the accepted answer will not work...

Any suggestions?

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 201 Ok
Date: Fri, 10 Nov 2017 08:47:06 GMT
Server: Apache
content-length: 100
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
cache-control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Connection: close

{"user":"1234......
```

Comment: Could you please post expected output in code tags too? As it is not clear.

Comment: The expected output is the JSON content: {"user":"1234","dept":"IT"}. To make things worse, the "HTTP/1.1 100 Continue" header may or may not appear in the output.

Comment: Quite unclear...  Why not just grep for { ?  Nothing else has it right?

Comment: Add your curl command to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude the headers and print only the json response using `sed` or `awk`, looking for the first occurence of `{` at the beginning of a line.

```
sed -n '/^{/,$p' file
awk '/^{/{p=1} p' file
```

It seems that you have already executed `curl` with `-i` or whatever so that you get these headers. In case you don't really need them, get only the response with a simple `curl` without parameter for including headers, default printing of `curl` is enough to exclude headers.

Comment: Headers are needed to parse and get the HTTP response code, if a 500 series is received there is no need to try to get the remaining content and other aproach should be taken, sed worked pretty well for what I needed thanks.